# Edit Path in my twig file

Tags: symfony, path, twig

I have a variable extracted in my Twig file which is the result of a selected :

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="product-information"><!--/product-information-->
                <img src="images/product-details/new.jpg" class="newarrival" alt="" />
                <h2>{{ produit.nom }}</h2>
                <p>{{ produit.categorie.nomcat }}</p>
                <p>{{ produit.description }}</p>
                <span>
                    <span>€ {{ produit.prix}}</span>

                </span>
                <p>
                    <script>
                        function myFunction() {
                            var x = document.getElementById("co").value;
                                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
                            }
                    </script>
                    <b>Couleur :</b>
                    <select id="co" onchange="myFunction()">
                        {% for coul in produit.couleur %}
                            <option value="{{ coul.nomc }}">{{ coul.nomc }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </p>                            

                <p><b>Marque :</b> {{ produit.marque}}</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="{{ path('ajouter', { 'id' : produit.id }) }}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-fefault cart" >
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                            Ajouter au Panier
                        </button>   
                    </a>
                </p>


            </div><!--/product-information-->
```

i try to extract the selected item from the select by put it in a variable,
somthing like that : `{% set var %}   <p id=demo> </p>`

when i put the variable {{ var }}  i get the selected item in my screen 
but when i put it in the path i get the problem :
the path is somthing like that : ../../../id/ /

he put the balise p not the value of my variable

I have tried : `<a href="{{ path('ajouter', { 'id' : produit.id, 'coul' : {{ var }} }) }}">`

Comment: (*from the comments in the answer*) You can't pass javascript variables towards `twig`, as `twig` is rendered serverside; Consider using `ajax` to fetch the correct path

Comment: thx for answer , i use this script    ` <script>   
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                 $("#co").change(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                    data:  {keyname:$('#co option:selected').val()}
                         });
                        });
                                    });</script> ` but how can i get the result and put it in the path

Comment: Reading the comments, your `var` is a result of a javascript process right?! Then it's already too late to implement it in twig. Javascript is a client-side process, not a server-side one. Can you edit your question and provide us with the twig file as well as the javascript plz?

Comment: So, cool you added some more code... Now tell me... When do you close the function `myFunction`? When do you use `var x` or return it? Where do you call `myFunction`? As it's... It will never work for that it's "bugged" and you never use the result

Answer (score 0):

you can use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) to generate routes on client side (right in JS)